# Combining variable number of fields across data.frame, using mapply

Tags: r, mapply

I have data frame with columns of characters, let's say `tdf <- data.frame(words=letters[1:4], words2=letters[5:8], word3=letters[9:12])`

I have also a corresponding vector stating the last column number to be used for combining the words in each rows, let's say `tcol <- c(3, 1, 1, 2)`

So for example for the fourth row, the output should be `"d h"`.

I wrote a function that can handle the merging of each row

```
xyp <- function(x, y) do.call(paste, as.list(x[1:y]))
```

which works as expected with a `for` loop

```
> y <- character(0)
> for (x in 1:nrow(tdf)) y <- c(y, xyp(tdf[x, ], tcol[x]))
> y
[1] "a e i" "b"     "c"     "d h"
```

I'd like to apply the function across the data frame without using `for` loop, but the function above doesn't seem to work for this purpose.

```
> mapply(xyp, tdf, tcol)
  words  words2   word3    <NA> 
"a b c"     "e"     "i"   "a b" 
Warning message:
In mapply(xyp, tdf, tcol) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

I think I understand the error, but am not sure what I can do to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: `mapply` will work on data.frame columns, not rows. So you need something like `mapply(xyp, data.frame(t(tdf)), tcol)` I think. That's not perfect by any means though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
mapply(function(x, i) paste(x[1:i], collapse=" "), 
    split(as.matrix(tdf),row(tdf)), 
    tcol)
```

Here we use `split()` to slice the data.frame into a list of rows rather than a list of columns as is usually the case with a data.frame.

Comment: Or `split(tdf,rownames(tdf))` - they have to be unique in a data.frame, so it will split each row.